# Returning multiple elements of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just have a simple question I need to write a function that takes a list as a parameter and returns a new list containing all the elements of the parameter data but with the last item appearing twice.

This is what I have:

```
def duplicate_last(data):
    return data[:], data[-1]
```

So duplicate_last([1,2,3]) comes out as ([1, 2, 3], 3) but I need it in the format of [1, 2, 3, 3].

Solution?

Also can't get

```
   return data[:] + data[-1]
```

to work as "can only concatenate list (not "int") to list"

Answer (score 3):

You could make a slight amendment to your current code:

```
def duplicate_last(data):
    return data[:] + [data[-1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a list.

You have:

```
def duplicate_last(data):
    return data[:], data[-1]
```

That creates a tuple with two elements, a copy of the list (`data[:]`) and the last element of the list.

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem with `data[:] + data[-1]` is -- you're trying to use a `list + list` construction but you're doing `list + int`.

Solutions:

```
new_list = data[:]
new_list.append(data[-1])
return new_list
```

Or fix the `TypeError` directly:

```
return data[:] + [data[-1]]
```

With the extra brackets it's `list + list` again.

You can also do this with slicing, which always returns a list:

```
return data[:] + data[-1:]
```

Of the 3, I would probably use the last solution because it seems to me the most readable. Any of the 3 is fine, though.